# Masking two shapefiles with MultiLineString and MultiPolygon errors

Tags: vector-layer, differences, multi-polygon

I created a shapefile by converting a raster to a polygon using raster pixels to polygon tool and used this as a base layer to remove unwanted areas with difference tool. I added multiple shapefiles and created a final base layer using this difference tool:

[image]

I have now downloaded a shapefile that I also want to layer on to the base layer:

[image]

I want to use the difference tool to get a new final area that removes any area that overlaps between the two shapefiles (The new smaller yellow area):

[image]

Previously when running into errors using the difference tool I simply changed the settings:

[image]

However, when I run the difference tool between these two layers I run into a new error:

[image]

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please show us the input layers used in the `Difference tool`? It seems from the input message that one of the layers is MultiLinesString (Line layer) which cannot be used in the `Difference tool`.

Comment: I have decided to save the output file as a gpkg file and this has managed to solve the issue, but not sure why

Comment: Then it is better to post your solution as an answer to help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by saving the output file as a gpkg file rather than a shapefile and managed to get a new layer that contains the correct information